# How should I sort object? By shaders or by meshes?

Tags: sorting, opengl-es, drawing

To minimize count of state changes, I should sort drawing order of meshes. Anyway If I have multiple meshes using multiple shaders, I need to choose sorting by one of vertex attribute bindings or shader uniform parameters.

What should I choose? I think I have to choose minimizing vertex attribute change because of GPU cache hit rate, but I have no idea about shader changing cost. What's the generic concern when deciding drawing order? Can I get some basis to choose this?

PS. I'm targeting iOS/PowerVR SGX chips.

### Edit

I decided to go sort-by-material because many meshes will use just a few materials, but there're bunch of meshes to draw. This means I will have more opportunity to share materials than share meshes. So it will have more chance to decrease state change count. Anyway I'm not sure, so if you have better opinion, please let me know.

Comment: Are all your meshes rendered using the same shader?

Comment: @arul No there're many meshes using different many shaders and some meshes shares shaders. So it's making me to think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to depth sort opaque objects on the PowerVR SGX since  uses order-independent, pixel perfect hidden surface removal. 
Depth sort only to achieve proper transparency/translucency rendering.

The best practice on SGX is to sort by state, in the following order:

- Viewport
- Framebuffer
- Shader
- Textures
- Clipping, Blending etc.

Texture state change can be significantly reduced by using texture atlases.
The amount of draw calls can be reduced by batching.

Thats just the golden rules, remember that you should profile first and then optimize :)

See:
http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/docs/PowerVR.Performance%20Recommendations.1.0.28.External.pdf

Comment: How about vertex/index buffers? Is changing them cheaper than listed states?

Comment: yes, these operations are cheap, better yet, you can use VAOs (Vertex Array Objects) to handle them conveniently.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=86 and then you can change which parts are sorted first in your code at run time to achieve the best speeds per device